# Android SeekBar thumb Customization

Tags: android, progress-bar, seekbar

I want to hide bar and only want to show thumb. I did it with max-height=0dip but it did not completely work. I also want to set text on thumb and create thumb with multiple images. For example thumb which i button like image and has text and this button has tail downword, which increases with row increment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Regarding removing the background, I managed to do this in the following way. Here, the blank drawable is a transparent png of 1x1 pixel

```
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/blank"
     />
```

You can also change the drawable by using:

```
android:thumb="@drawable/icon"
```

To add text, I guess you'll have to create a [custom component](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

Comment: I used this method as well, but it seems to be a bit of a hack.  There isn't a better way to do this?

Comment: I did it by setting:
  android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"
in the xml

Answer (score 2):

```
  SeekBar seekbar = new SeekBar(context, attrs);

     // ------------- custom thumb
            //----- using resources 

    seekbar.setThumb(new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
         context.getResources(), R.drawable.seekbar_progress_thumb)));
          //----- or using shape drawable


    ShapeDrawable thumb = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    thumb.getPaint().setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
    thumb.setIntrinsicHeight(-80);
    thumb.setIntrinsicWidth(30);
    seekbar.setThumb(thumb);
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to hide the bar, you can set opacity value using hex colors. You just need to add the right prefix.
I hid the seekBar using this code:

```
android:progressBackgroundTint="#00555555"
android:progressTint="#00555555"
```

Where the first two ciphers (i.e. "00") set opaqueness (alpha percentage) and the other six (i.e. "555555") set the color.

Check this post for more information and a list of hex opacity values:
[Understanding colors on Android (six characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445085/understanding-colors-in-android-6-characters/11019879#11019879)