# TextView and background color

Tags: android, colors, textview, background-color

I want to set a transparent black color to my `textview` background color. How can I do it?

Comment: Transparent or black because transparent black doesn't make sense :)

Comment: Actually I need light black like dialog box background Is this possible?

Comment: [this ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608947/android-transparent-textview) may help you to give transparent background for a text view.

Comment: You can refer this link <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android">Transparent</a> This link is helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
          <gradient 
            android:startColor="#2fDEDEDE"
            android:endColor="#2F000000"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:color="#cbc9c9" />

        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" /> 

        <padding
            android:left="5dp"
            android:top="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:bottom="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>

            <gradient
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:angle="270" />

            <stroke
            android:color="#c3c2c2" />

        <corners
            android:radius="4dp" /> 

        <padding
            android:left="5dp"
            android:top="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:bottom="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

usage:==> 
`android:background="@drawable/btn_trans"`

if you want to set black color

```
android:background="#000"
```

Answer (score 8):

```
android:background="#55000000"
```

If you use a color with 8 numbers instead of 6, the first two set the opacity.  in this case, the opacity is 0x55 which is 85/255 [roughly 33% opacity].

for programatic, you should be able to use the following (where myTextView corresponds to your View)

```
myTextView.setBackgroundColor(0x55000000);
```

Comment: The only post answering OP question, IMO

Answer (score 0):

make a image transparent in photoshop and apply it to textview background...
thats it , you have got transparent background to text view

Answer (score 0):

Set backgroud color as follows

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```