# How to make text color as transparent in listview android?

Tags: java, android, textview, transparent

I need to change Text color based on background image. My background image contains multiple colors. So, accordingly i have to change my textview color.

```
  <TextView    android:id="@+id/txtbloops_flower"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:textSize="16dp"
               android:layout_centerInParent="true"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
               android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

[image]

please guide me, how to do this.

Answer (score 7):

Basically you have the option to set the transparency (opacity) and the color using android:background.

The hex value that you set it to is composed of 3 to 4 parts:

- Alpha (opacity), i'll refer to that as aa
- Red, i'll refer to it as rr
- Green, i'll refer to it as gg
- Blue, i'll refer to it as bb

Without an alpha (transparency) value:

```
android:background="#rrggbb"
```

With an alpha (transparency) value:

```
android:background="#aarrggbb"
```

The alpha value for full transparency is 00 and the alpha value for no transparency is FF

You can experiment with values in between those.

Comment: Hey, you should refer to the original post if this answer was copied from somewhere else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608947/android-transparent-textview

Answer (score 5):

Try out with `android:textColor="#00000000"`. This code is for the transparent color only.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the text color try using #24ffffff or some other combination, the first two digits are for the alpha, and you can adjust the opacity of the text.

Answer (score 0):

set text color: `#80000000`

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtbloops_flower"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="hello dhaval"
            android:textColor="#80000000"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
```

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6873336/1168654)

Answer (score 0):

To get transparency in any of your color add `88` or `44` before your color code as per your requirement of transparency level.
for example, to get black transparent color use code "#88000000"

so just get your color code and add the prefix to it and set the color as below example.

```
android:textColor="#88000000"
```