# How to make TextView's background to be transparent?

Tags: android

There is a tablelayout having four tablerows, the first tablerow contains a TextView :

[image]

As you can see the background of the TextView having the text "Vidy" is seen ! So how to make it transparent ? I tried to add android:alpha="0" to the attribute of the TextView but at runtime the text is not seen !

Comment: textviews are transparent by default, are you sure that is a textview?

Comment: Could you please post the layout and class code?

Comment: set Textview background as `android:background="#00000000"` and try.

Comment: @tyczj is right! Looks more like a button to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
android:background="@null"
```

Or:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Check also: [Android Transparent TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608947/android-transparent-textview)

Answer (score 2):

If you really need transparency, @Nermeen's answer is great, you can also get it done programmatically like:

```
myTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

but as long as you have solid background color below, it's better due to performance to make your `TextView`'s background color the same as the layout below (with alpha, app needs to redraw more regions). It won't really matter for such a simple layout, but it's worth remembering when you have many of them using transparency.