# Background image in ImageView causes crash

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview

I have an image called `down.png` in the drawables folder, but every time I run the app, it crashes on creation.

This is my `MainActivity` code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ImageView  sss = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sss);
    Button ddd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    ddd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //sss.setImageResource(R.drawable.down);
            sss.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.down);
            //sss.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.down));

        }
    });


}
```

This is the XML I am using:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/activity_main_layout"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/sss"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sss"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="111dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my Logcat output:

```
04-28 07:11:09.637    1359-1359/prosis.teste D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-28 07:11:09.637    1359-1359/prosis.teste W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a99ba8)
04-28 07:11:09.687    1359-1359/prosis.teste E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: prosis.teste, PID: 1359
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{prosis.teste/prosis.teste.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at prosis.teste.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 07:11:14.327    1359-1359/prosis.teste  I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1359 SIG: 9
```

All the commands that are in comments are where I tried and failed. `line 35` (the one that appears in logcat) is the line where the code to make the change is;
why is that code causing a crash?

Comment: need to post to logcat to reach the exact problem

Comment: please specify line `35` in `Mainactivity` as per `prosis.teste.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)`

Comment: post your activity's oncreate method

Comment: Look at here is posted answer

Comment: Post ur entire MainActivity code including line numbers. Also there is no problem with ur code, only thing i found in xml would be adding this line
**android:layout_alignParentRight="true"** for image view if ur using API 15 and also this **android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"** for button thats all..
The code above worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView  sss = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sss);
        Button ddd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        ddd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 sss.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

use this code ....I think you forgot to add **setContentView()** method...

Answer (score 1):

you should be using

1. `setImageResource(R.drawable.down);`
2. `setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.down));`

instead of `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img1);`.

Comment: @NobodyNemo ..try these apis ,may be it helps

Comment: @Anshuman To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

firstly put your image inside image view,then try to make your button,textView,editText etc transparent(No need to set it dynamically,you can make those changes through your xml).

and go through 
[Android Transparent TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608947/android-transparent-textview)

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this simple code to draw in background image at ImageView 

 <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />

or 
<ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />

or 
 programmatically
 img..setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Comment: best way is middle or second answer in my answer