# How to make EditText's background Translucent? I tried changing the color to #80000000 but it makes my edittext look even darker

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-edittext

I am designing a Login Screen With `Xamarin`. I want my `Edittext's` background as translucent. I have attached screenshots.

This is how my Edittext looks now, with background #00000000
[image]

This is how I want it to look like
[image]

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Post your whole layout file maybe ;) I think you're setting the background color in the wrong tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `EditText` looks completely transparent due to `#00000000`.

Use following table to achieve transparency

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

also If you need more customization, plz go to Android studio --> `colors.xml` click on color which looks just beside line numbers, click on that color. It will show you color Dialog. Slide bottom Opacity bar to achieve your transparency.

Answer (score 0):

try this `android:background="#07000000"` in your XML file.and for more information 
Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608947/android-transparent-textview)

Answer (score 0):

add to "color.xml":

```
<color name="GreyTransparent">#55A0A0A0</color>
```

add new "background.xml" to drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/GreyTransparent"/>
</shape>
```

in your layout:

```
   <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="@drawable/background"
             android:padding="3dp"/>
```

Comment: I tried this, it is making the edittext grey not translucent.

Comment: this not looking like the screenshot that i have uploaded :l

Comment: you can add any color you want .... if you have color=#A0A0A0 , add after # value from 00 to FF, for white for example: #55FFFFFF

Comment: Like in **Pratim P's** answer