# Translucent seekbar

Tags: android, transparency, seekbar

I prefer if I could my the seekbar in my app looks Translucent, is this possible?

```
<SeekBar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topBar"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:max="100"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner" >
        </SeekBar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `android:progressDrawable` attribute to a custom `layer-list` drawable with translucent components. You can set the `android:thumb` property as well.

Here's a sample drawable xml from [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere), you can reference that project for sample image assets, too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/progress_bg_holo_dark" />

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
               android:drawable="@drawable/progress_secondary_holo_dark" />
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
               android:drawable="@drawable/progress_primary_holo_dark" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Also - related question:

[Custom Drawable for ProgressBar/ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog)

Comment: What is `progress_bg_holo_dark`?

Answer (score 0):

In your XML, add this attribute :

```
android:alpha = "floatValue"
```

or, in the java code use

```
setAlpha(floatValue)
```

It enables you to change the **alpha property** of the view.

0 = completely transparent

1 = completely opaque

So, for translucent, you can set to 0.5 or any value according to the transparency you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You can set opacity value using hex colors. You just need to add the right prefix.
I hid the seekBar using this code:

```
android:progressBackgroundTint="#00555555"
android:progressTint="#00555555"
```

Where the first two ciphers (i.e. "00") set opaqueness (alpha percentage) and the other six (i.e. "555555") set the color.

Check this post for more information and a list of hex opacity values:
[Understanding colors on Android (six characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445085/understanding-colors-in-android-6-characters/11019879#11019879)