# How to create transparent activity in android?

Tags: android, alpha-transparency

How to create transparent activity in android in that screen tap to dismiss button automatically  dismiss the activity. please provide any solution.

[image]

Comment: So I get that you want to have transparent activity, but what do you want to accomplish on tapping issue?

Comment: gothrough http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android

Comment: in manifest, in particular activity you want to be transparent, use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"

Comment: Why don't you use a transparent view instead of an activity? You can put a transparent view on your activity.

Comment: Hi all this problem is solving implemntation is done , thank u very much for sharing information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Transparent Activity in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this

- use the following theme for activity.

> android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"

- Set background of the activity as a trans parent png image or a transparent code

eg.

> android:background="@drawable/transparent_bg"

or

> android:background="#33BBFFFF"

```
this is a semi transparent color
```

Related Links

[How to make a background 20% transparent on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285961/how-to-make-a-background-transparent-20-in-android)

[Understanding colors on Android (six characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445085/understading-colors-in-android-6-chars)

- To dismiss activity on tap implement [onTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and when touch event is detected call finish();

Hope it helps !!

Comment: android:background="#33BBFFFF" did not give me a transparent background when applied to the RelativeActivity. It just gave me a white background. -1

Answer (score 9):

Works better with noTitleBar to create a full transparent activity

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

and remember extends your activity from Activity and not from AppCompactActivity

If you need to use AppCompact then declare a new theme:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
</style>
```