# Activity as dialog from BroadcastReceiver over another activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

My app listens for an `Intent` fired by a third party app when an `Activity` in that app is shown. The `Intent` is received in a `BroadcastReceiver` in my app. I want to start an Activity from the `BroadcastReceiver` which will show as a `Dialog` over the existing `activity` (that fired the Intent).

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.d(TAG, ">>>>>>>>> Action:" + action);

    if ("clover.intent.action.V1_ORDER_BUILD_START".equals(action)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), ActiveOrderActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

The Intent `clover.intent.action.V1_ORDER_BUILD_START` is fired by a different app which my app listens for. When this Intent is fired, an Activity is already open (see the background activity in the picture below).

Now I want to show an Activity in my app as Dialog over the already shown activity, just like the "Add Customer to Order" in the image below.

As shown in the code above, I am starting an Activity from `BroadcastReceiver`, but when it starts, it comes to foreground and the previous Activity is not shown.

See below for an example of what I want to achieve,

[image: Example UI of what i would like to achieve]

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: See following post probably help : [How to create transparent activity in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332064/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should create

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflaterViewObject = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    final View DialogView = inflaterViewObject.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    final AlertDialog Dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
    Dialog.setView(DialogView);

    DialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_YES).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //your YES logic
            Dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    DialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_NO).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //Your NO LOGIC
            Dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    // return dialog object (later on .show());
    return Dialog;
}
```

Later you write in your choosen place (in BrodcastReciever)

```
MyDialog dialogObject = new MyDialog();
dialogObject.show(getFragmentManager(), "tag name for the dialog fragment.");
```