# Taking screenshot in BroadCast Receiver class Android

Tags: android

I am calling a BroadcastReceiver class using AlarmManager and Pending Intent. It is scheduled for daily basis.

The following is the code for BroadCast Receiver class which is called in the Activity(It is a separate class).

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Hello", "Hi");
        Intent mIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.foodonz.android");
        if(mIntent!=null)
        {
            context.startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem statement is that in this Receiver I am opening another application and I want to capture the screenshot and upload it to the server. But Window feature is not available in Broadcast receiver class and I cant implement as I am out of Activity control.

Key Challenge:

-Implement screenshot taking and uploading to server code in the following class

Any solutions for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have access of window in broadcast receiver and in service dont let u take screen shot. So , in my sense in receiver you can open transparent activity and take screenshot in that activity. Following is the link to create transparent activity.

[Create transparent activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332064/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Let me know if its helpful or not.