# Apply color filter on button

Tags: android, button, colors, background

I have a lot of button with a lot of different background colors. I want to know if there is a way to apply some color filter on click. For example, i want that all my buttons become darker on click. They keep the original color, but it's darker.

Is there an easy way to do it, or i have to define the darker color for each button?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this for apply color filter with alpha value
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445085/understanding-colors-in-android-6-chars

Answer (score 7):

I assume you want the button to darken on touch, and revert to normal when the user releases the button.

I would suggest creating a custom button which does the work for you:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.LightingColorFilter;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DarkenButton extends Button {

    public DarkenButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DarkenButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // darken background
            getBackground().setColorFilter(
                    new LightingColorFilter(0xff888888, 0x000000));
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // clear color filter
            getBackground().setColorFilter(null);
            break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

Then use DarkenButton anywhere you would normally use a Button.

Comment: Suppose someone used a solution of an overlay over the imageView, with a color that has specific alpha (like #33445566), what should I put into the first parameter of the LightingColorFilter , to replace the previous solution with this one ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I don't think I understand. How are you implementing the overlay?

Comment: Just another view in the container of this view, on top of the current view. This makes a layer of a semi-transpared color on top of the current view.

Comment: Then I don't see why you would need to set a filter at all. I'd say it's not nearly as flexible a solution though

Comment: Well, avoiding creation of more views is always welcomed. Plus, think that it needs to be added for each button.

Answer (score 5):

Try this-

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            v.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFAA0000));

            }


        }
```

and for clear filter do this

```
button.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to define the darker color of each button and onclick of those button assign the new darker color