# Devices seem to handle color filters differently

Tags: android, porter-duff

I have a button with a `colorPrimary` (red) background. In certain cases I have to apply a color filter on the background:
`myButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.background_grey), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);`
This works the way it should.

I also need to be able to undo this. I tried `setColorFilter(null)` and `clearColorFilter()` (which in turn calls `setColorFilter(null)`). This works fine on most devices. However, on some devices the button turns white instead of red. Tapping the button seems to set the background back to red (first `colorPrimaryDark` and then back to `colorPrimary`)

There are just a few devices that show this behaviour, one of them is the LG G3 Vigor.

Is there a way to get this correct on any device?

Comment: You mean with the same universal source, and using the Android setColorFilter API? No. Lot of devices contain small bugs in implementation and their behaviour may differ, I'm actually surprised you didn't find any device which would not do the filtering at all (probably your lowest API requirements are high enough to avoid those). But maybe try something like invalidate() after setColorFilter(null), to redraw the button completely?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947322/apply-color-filter-on-button

Comment: @Ped7g Unfortunately, that doesn't do the trick :( Min API level is 19 by the way.

Comment: One more try, try to re-set after setColorFilter(null) the whole background with original drawable/color? (I think that will do the invalidate() inside, but if it doesn't help, just add invalidate to be sure it does not work)