# How to darken colors opacity in Hex code

Tags: html, css, colors

After reading this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445085/understanding-colors-in-android-6-chars), I know how to lighten the opacity of a color.

But is there any method to darken the color's opacity?

Comment: Do you mean make the opacity more transparent?   This is covered by the alpha channel as specified in the 8 digit definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "darken opacity" you mean moving from a clear blue to a dark blue, and if your question concern HTML/CSS (and not Android like your link suppose) you could use HSL Colors instead of using RGB.

Here is a link where you can find out how tu use CSS colors : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp

```
    /** This is CSS **/
    #light {background-color:hsl(120,100%,25%);}
    #normal {background-color:hsl(120,100%,50%);}
    #dark {background-color:hsl(120,100%,75%);}
    /** 3rd value reprensent black value **/
```

But if you just mean make your color more/less opaque, you could just use `Alpha` (Available in RGBA in CSS for example)

You can find out how to use RGBA in the 1st link to!

```
    /** This is CSS **/
    #opaque {background-color:rgba(0,255,0,1);}
    #transparant {background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);}
    /** The 4th value reprensent alpha/opacity and goes from 0 (transparant) to 1 (opaque)
```

#### Hope it helped you

Answer (score 0):

The way to darken a particular colour is to keep the RBG ratios the same but just lower the numbers, if you look at RBG for black its 0,0,0 so by being closer to 0 you get a darker colour.

Hope that sheds a bit of light on how RBG colour system works.