# Android design library 22.2.0 status bar semi transparent dark primary with the content behind the status bar

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, android-statusbar

Using the `design lib 22.2.0`, how can I manage to put the content behind the `StatusBar` (in my case it's a map) and to color the `StatusBar` in semi transparent primary dark color (could be semi transparent red)

See picture from another SO post:

[image]

I'm not using the `ScrimInsetFrameLayout`.

I tried setting `fitsSystemWindows="false"` on the `DrawerLayout` so my content can lay behind the status bar but the color isn't applied to it.

If I set `fitsSystemWindows="true"` applies the color to the `StatusBar` but the content does not lay behind it.

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26932228/1228221

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate:

The answer in this post works:
[Lollipop : draw behind statusBar with its color set to transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856603/lollipop-draw-behind-statusbar-with-its-color-set-to-transparent)