# Add a ListView or RecyclerView to new NavigationView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, navigationview

I am using the new [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) from revision 22.2.0 of the [support library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) by Google. It works perfectly fine to generate a navigation drawer populated using a menu res.

I was wondering is it possible to add a ListView or RecyclerView to the navigation drawer so that it can be populated using my custom adapter code, which allows for far greater flexibility than menu resources.

Here is my current XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/main_toolbar" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Where in my XML would I add the ListView or RecyclerView?

**EDIT**

As per Basant's suggestion, I nested a ListView into the NavigationView. You lose the ability to inflate from a menu res (as far as I know) but it succeeds in what I want it to do. The header XML is unchanged, it is just included into XML.

New code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/main_toolbar" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_header_include"
                layout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/navigation_drawer_header_include"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can just nest the `ListView` or `RecyclerView` inside the `NavigationView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/main_toolbar" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/menuList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**NOTE:** Keep in mind that if you use use a ListView inside it, you can't use the NavigationView's header. You will have to use the header view of the ListView that you are adding. Don't forget to remove the `app:menu` and `app:header` fields.

Comment: Hello, I've tried that but the nav drawer breaks in the sense the navigation items are no longer clickable. Just saw your NOTE edit, I'll try that now.

Comment: I think you should not use the NavigationMenu in that case. Simply use a ListView or a more complex layout if you need, in place of a NavigationMenu. That will give you more flexibility.

Comment: The reason I want to use NavigationView is due to built in scrim handling to give it that more material look, I have applied your suggestion and it seems to work. I will update my post to show the new code.

Comment: Check out the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745300/navigation-drawer-semi-transparent-over-status-bar-not-working

Comment: I was previously using that but the new NavigationView has that built in and I prefer using the new view since it is part of the library.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it saved much of my time!

Answer (score 20):

If you want to adding views inside the NavigationView you can do something like this. This way you have no restriction of adding Header on your NavigtionView with ListView.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"

         >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <include layout="@layout/nav_header_main"
                android:id="@+id/my"
                />
            <ListView

                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/list_view_inside_nav"></ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

That look something like this

[image: example]

Comment: This will not scroll the header view like the Navigation View does

Comment: yes, you can put them into linear layout with orientation vertical and then put in into scrollview with parameter fillViewPort = true

Comment: It tried but AFAIK (remember) whenever i am opening navigation drawer containing recycler view instead of listview the view don't show header rather than it was scrolled down to recycler view. @deadfish

Comment: @Shubham have you add header above the recyclerview inside navigationview

Comment: i have used a similar design pattern but recycler view inside a scroll view but my layout scrolling lags

Answer (score 5):

In response to Shubham's comment

> This will not scroll the header view like the Navigation View does

I solved it by putting the `LinearLayout` inside a `NestedScrollView`. Now it scrolls properly with the header.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/nav_header_main" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/weight_based_height"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Try this way**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigation"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/nav_header" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lst_menu_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```