# ListView getting overlapped by another layout

Tags: android, xml, listview, navigation-drawer

Good morning. I have a layout like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...
  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/jet"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/action_menu" />

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/navList"
      android:layout_width="200dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="left|start"
      android:background="@color/chalk" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And then, on my Activity I populate the ListView like this:

```
String[] osArray = {"CERRAR SESIÓN", "ACERCA DE"};
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

My issue is that the layout I'm using as a header for the drawer, overlaps the ListView. I have tried also giving the ListView a marginTop, but although that works in Android Studio (apparently), it solves nothing when running the code.

Just in case, here is the layout I use as a header for the drawer:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
    android:background="@color/accent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/header_left_padding"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/user_name"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/email"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/user_email"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the `NavigationView` and the older design pattern for `DrawerLayout`. In older days we have to use listView to populate the drawer menu but with creation of `NavigationView` we now put what we want into the xml files. so your layout should be:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...
  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/jet"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/action_menu" />



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and you must populate your drawer menu by these two xml files

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
app:menu="@menu/action_menu"
```

you can use `@layout/drawer_header` to design the header menu and `action_menu` to create your list items of the drawer menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

> Theme.Appcompat

Instead of theme overlay for the linear layout

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't change a thing.

Comment: Please view this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978114/add-a-listview-or-recyclerview-to-new-navigationview you might find some valuable information here

Comment: Thanks. It will help me for a future update on the code.