# Android : add menuItem in NavigationView pragmatically from webservice

Tags: android, menuitem, android-navigationview

In NavigationView of my app has several menus but I wanted to user only access particular menus. According to user privilege user will able to view only his accessible menus. So I created webservice which return me list of menus.

Here is json output of menu access

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "appId": "1",
    "userId": "1",
    "name": "Design List",
    "icon": "http://some_website/Demo/images/menu/1.png",
    "code": "dsn001"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "appId": "1",
    "userId": "1",
    "name": "Price List",
    "icon": "http://some_website/Demo/images/menu/2.png",
    "code": "prc002"
  },
  ....]
```

For example user has only access to this menus. I have a navigationview ready in application. I wanted to add this menus to navigationview.

In android I created a model class for menu

> MenuItems.java

```
public class MenuItems {

    public String id;
    public String appId;
    public String userId;
    public String name;
    public String icon;
    public String code;
}
```

In webservice response, I converted response to `ArrayList<MenuItems>()` 
here is webservice code.

```
ArrayList<MenuItems> menuItem = new ArrayList<MenuItems>();
.
.
MenuItems[] items = new Gson().fromJson(response, MenuItems[].class);
for (MenuItems m : items) {
    menuItem.add(m);
}
```

In main activity I did this code.

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    if (menuList != null) {
        for (MenuItems items : menuList) {
            MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(items.name);
            menuItem.setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(items.icon));
        }
    }
```

But still it didn't work.

I wanted display this menus with icon in navigationview.
can we show icon using Picaso library? please help.

Comment: did you mean adding menu items to NavigationDrawer of your APP ?

Comment: You need to do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978114/add-a-listview-or-recyclerview-to-new-navigationview).

Comment: @HasifSeyd yes. I want to add menu in o NavigationDrawer.

Comment: @EricB. Thanks, I think it may work. I am trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding Navigation menuItems Dynamically, you should get the Menu object from the NavigationView at run time like this. also fetch the icons from the server and keep it.

```
    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
```

then add the List of menu to it

```
    for (MenuItems item : items) {
        MenuItem lNavigationMenuItem = menu.add(groupId, itemId, order, title);
        //fetch the bitmap from the server asynchronously before and add it to the menu as follows 
        lNavigationMenuItem.setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
    }
```

Comment: but my list is not `MenuItem` type. its `MenuItems`

Comment: yeah, so whats the doubt ?? okay use whatever type you are using , i have just provided the logic

Comment: inside the for-loop "MenuItem lNavigationitem" is from package android.view.MenuItem

Comment: see my edited question I have added your logic still my menus are empty.