# Unable to display translucent Android Status Bar

Tags: android, statusbar

I have followed some examples online to implement a Navigation Drawer + Action Bar + Translucent Status Bar. The translucent status bar does not turn into transparent at all.

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name="com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.sample.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

v21/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="menu_labels_style">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/fab_label_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/simplify_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<!-- Beginning of Navigation Drawer -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- Beginning of Floating Action Menu -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
            android:id="@+id/simplify_actions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/simplify_blue"
            fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/simplify_blue_pressed"
            fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/white"
            fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/action_scan_qr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_title="SCAN QR CODE"
                fab:fab_size="mini"
                fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_scan_qr_code"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/action_share_hotspot"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_title="SHARE HOTSPOT"
                fab:fab_size="mini"
                fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_share_wifi"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/action_discovery"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_title="SEARCH NETWORK"
                fab:fab_size="mini"
                fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_discover_network"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

        </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
        <!-- End of Floating Action Menu -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="304dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
<!-- End of Navigation Drawer -->
```

and the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private boolean IS_HOTSPOT_ON = false;

String TITLES[] = {"Profile","Payment","History","Promotions","Usage","Speed","Settings"};
int ICONS[] = {R.drawable.ic_profile,R.drawable.ic_payment,R.drawable.ic_history,R.drawable.ic_promotion,R.drawable.ic_usage,R.drawable.ic_speed,R.drawable.ic_settings};
String NAME = "Yoona Im";
String EMAIL = "yoona@nextwave.my";
int PROFILE = R.drawable.yoona;

private Toolbar toolbar;

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;                           // Declaring   RecyclerView
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;                        // Declaring Adapter For Recycler View
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;            // Declaring Layout Manager as a linear layout manager
DrawerLayout Drawer;                                  // Declaring DrawerLayout

ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;                  // Declaring Action Bar Drawer Toggle

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


  toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);

  mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View

  mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size

  mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES,ICONS,NAME,EMAIL,PROFILE);       // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
  // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
  // and header view profile picture

  mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView

  mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager

  mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager

  Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);        // Drawer object Assigned to the view

  mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close){


      @Override
      public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
          super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
          // code here will execute once the drawer is opened( As I dont want anything happened whe drawer is
          // open I am not going to put anything here)
      }

      @Override
      public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
          super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
          // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
      }

  }; // Drawer Toggle Object Made



final FloatingActionsMenu menuSimplifyActions = (FloatingActionsMenu) findViewById(R.id.simplify_actions);

final FloatingActionButton actionScanQR = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.action_scan_qr);
  actionScanQR.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
      actionScanQR.setTitle("SCANNING CODE NOW...");
  }
});

final FloatingActionButton actionShareHotspot = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.action_share_hotspot);
  actionShareHotspot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {

          if (!IS_HOTSPOT_ON) {
              actionShareHotspot.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_disable_hotspot);
              actionShareHotspot.setTitle("SWITCH OFF HOTSPOT");
          }
          else {
              actionShareHotspot.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_share_wifi);
              actionShareHotspot.setTitle("SHARE HOTSPOT");
          }

          IS_HOTSPOT_ON = !IS_HOTSPOT_ON;
      }
  });

  Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle
  mDrawerToggle.syncState();               // Finally we set the drawer toggle sync State

}


@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Comment: Translucent turns the status bar to translucent, and not transparent, from the code you have written, it clearly sets the status bar to translucent, and allows UI to draw underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
```

to

```
 <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

this will transparent your status bar.

Comment: Thanks. How could I change the Navigation Bar to show on top of the status bar? Currently it is showing underneath the status bar.

Comment: <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item> do this

Comment: Hmm...doesn't have any effect.

Comment: go through this  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745300/navigation-drawer-semi-transparent-over-status-bar-not-working