# Drawable selector with same image but different opacity

Tags: android, xml, drawable

I want to save app space with next idea. But I'm not sure if it possible.

I want to have selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_forward" android:state_enabled="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_forward_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
</selector>
```

Where `arrow_forward` is png image and `arrow_forward_disabled` is same image but with 70% opacity. I've tried to achieve it with `layer-list` drawable but without success. Is there solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a ShapeDrawable, instead of a PNG, you CAN effect the colors you are using to set different Opacities, I will outline some options:

1. If you are using a ShapeDrawable, you could assign different opacities using the color (the first 2 chars in the color string are opacity, ie. #ffbada55 is no opacity green, and #80bada55 is a green with some opacity)
2. This wouldn't work for opacity, but you could apply a color filter using the API that exists (this may be a variation on your effect based on color, but still wouldn't allow you to change the opacity of your PNG)
   [Color Filter API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter.html)
3. Create custom PNGs, each with the opacity you need

I think (like the other answers) that Option #3 is simplest, and will work the best.

Bottom line, you can't change the opacity of a PNG resource using XML, you could create a Drawable (maybe use it as a background for your PNG), and you would be able to change the opacity of that using it's color resource definition.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to apply opacity in xml. It is only possible using two images.

-

You are using PNG files, you will have to create 2 png's with different opacities.

1º PNG - Enable. 100% opacity.

2º PNG - Disabled. 70% opacity.

After this, you need to create a selector XML with 2 different states:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_disabled" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_active" />
</selector>
```

You can also use shape buttons with different opacity using the alpha of ARGB (#AARRGGBB). Example: # 80FFFFFF (50% opacity)
([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445085/understanding-colors-in-android-6-characters/11019879#11019879))

Example:

Enabled:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#002aff" />
</shape>
```

Disabled (70% opacity: #b3002aff):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#b3002aff" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Hi @Alisson, thank you for answer. I know that I could use two images. The question was if I could use one image and define some opacity in xml drawable

Comment: There is no way to apply opacity in xml. It is only possible using two images.