# Styling issue after upgrading React-Native

Tags: css, react-native

I recently upgraded my React Native from `0.15` to `0.18`

Now when I run the app, it give the following error.

```
Invalid prop `backgroundColor` supplied to `StyleSheet mainContainer`.
StyleSheet mainContainer: {
  "justifyContent": "center",
  "alignItems": "center",
  "flexDirection": "row",
  "backgroundColor": "#fffffff",
  "marginBottom": -1
}
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The color you specified as background color is incorrect and does not exist. There is one `f` too many.
Either you can change it to:

```
"backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
```

Or you can also specify the white background color like this:

```
"backgroundColor": "white",
```

Here is an overview of all the supported color formats in React Native. You can also find the list for named colors there.
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/colors.html

Comment: That was to get Transparency. What should I use for Transparent in Hex?

Comment: In theory 50% transparent white in HEX would be `#80FFFFFF`. But this does not seem to work for me. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445085/understanding-colors-in-android-6-characters/11019879#11019879).

What does work for 50% transparent white is: 
`color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'`

Comment: Thank you. 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)' fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You have seven f characters in your background color rather than six - i.e it is invalid.

Try "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"