# What are the Material Design dark theme colors?

Tags: android, material-design

I'm looking for the color palette used by Material Design's Dark theme as found on this page:
http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

Any ideas? I've done a quick google and couldn't find anything about it. I'm looking for layout background, drawer background, appbar color, etc.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[This page](https://material.io/design/color/dark-theme.html) in the official material design website is dedicated to dark theme (including its colors). Here is the colors:

[image: Dark theme colors]

The image below compares Light and Dark theme colors (Light colors on the left side, Dark colors on the right):

[image: Light and Dark theme colors]

Image credits: [*official material design website*](https://material.io/design/color/dark-theme.html)

Answer (score 96):

***Update:*** the answer below contains a link to an archive of the Material docs. Check out the [current docs](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html) for the most up to date information.

Scroll to the bottom of the [color docs](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/style/color.html#color-themes) to see the dark theme colors.

[image]

Here is the text color info from the same docs:

[image]

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41121016/3681880) to convert those percentage values to hex.

Comment: Could it be that there is a mismatch between the opacity and the HEX values you provided? Here are the values that I got using Figma:
```js
{
  '0dp': '#121212',
  '1dp': '#1E1E1E',
  '2dp': '#232323',
  '3dp': '#252525',
  '4dp': '#272727',
  '6dp': '#2C2C2C',
  '8dp': '#2E2E2E',
  '12dp': '#333333',
  '16dp': '#363636',
  '24dp': '#383838',
}
```

Answer (score 34):

Here's some more information related to the same topic. According to the [Properties section in the Dark theme page of material.io](https://material.io/design/color/dark-theme.html#properties), the base color is `#121212`, but when you want to place an element over another one, you use a white layer with transparency to generate a lighter version of that grey. And this is what they share:

[image]

The problem with it is that that's great in terms of design, but it doesn't make our work that simple as a developers. So I got the photo editor and mapped that guidelines to hexadecimal colors. And here it is!

```
| elevation | overlay |   hex   |
| --------- | ------- | ------- |
|   00dp    |    0%   | #121212 |
|   01dp    |    5%   | #1e1e1e |
|   02dp    |    7%   | #222222 |
|   03dp    |    8%   | #242424 |
|   04dp    |    9%   | #272727 |
|   06dp    |   11%   | #2c2c2c |
|   08dp    |   12%   | #2e2e2e |
|   12dp    |   14%   | #333333 |
|   16dp    |   15%   | #343434 |
|   24dp    |   16%   | #383838 |
```