# Change EditText alpha without affecting the drawable and text opacity

Tags: android

I want this result :

[image]

but im having this:

[image]

I'am using this code :

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Destination *"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:background="#4d98d1"
            android:alpha="0.2"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/d"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:paddingLeft="30sp"
            android:paddingRight="26dip"
            android:focusable="false"/>
```

is there any change that I can apply here? or if I can do it programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the background as an ARGB color (with transparent alpha value) might work.

For example, change:

```
android:background="#4d98d1"
```

to:

```
android:background="#804d98d1"
```

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11019879/3363481) on alpha hex values for more information.