# Transparent symbols, solid lines, lattice::xyplot()

Tags: r, alpha, lattice

I want to plot two quantitative variables, in panels determined by a third factor variable, in R using lattice::xyplot(). I want **transparent** black symbols, with **solid** red trend lines. To provide a working example, I'll use the iris dataset in R. None of the four attempts below achieve the desired outcome (one of which was informed by the thread at [Add alpha value to lattice xyplot panel function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121784/add-alpha-value-to-lattice-xyplot-panel-function])):

```
library(datasets)
data(iris)

xyplot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width | Species, data = iris,
   type = c("p","smooth"), alpha=.1, pch=19, col="black", col.line="red", lwd=2)

xyplot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width | Species, data = iris,
   type = c("p","smooth"), 
   par.settings = list(superpose.symbol = list(cex=1, pch=20, col="black", alpha = 0.1),
                       superpose.line = list(col = "red", lwd = 2)))

xyplot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width | Species, data = iris, 
   grid = TRUE, scales=list(tck=c(1,0), x=list(cex=1.1), y=list(cex=1.1)),
   par.settings = list(superpose.symbol = list(pch =20, cex = 1, col = c("#0808084d"))),
   type = c("p", "smooth"), col.line =c("red"),lwd = 2)

xyplot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width | Species, data = iris,
   par.strip.text=list(cex=0.6),
   type = c("p","smooth"), 
   par.settings = list(superpose.symbol = list(cex=1, pch=20, col="black", alpha = 0.1),
                       superpose.line = list(col = "red", lwd = 2)))
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
trans_black <- adjustcolor("black",alpha.f=0.2)
xyplot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width | Species, data = iris,
       type = c("p","smooth"), pch=19, col=trans_black,
       col.line="red", lwd=2)
```

?