# SeekBar with custom thumb and segmented text

Tags: android, custom-controls, seekbar

[image]

Hello All,

I am looking for a seekbar like this image. I succeeded in setting background but problem is thumb and segments text below seek bar. Does anyone know solution
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this library](https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar) here is a minimum example code that worked for me:

```
<com.infteh.comboseekbar.ComboSeekBar
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/seekbar" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:color="#000"
        custom:textSize="12sp"
        custom:multiline="false"
        />
```

Then in the Activity

```
private ComboSeekBar mSeekBar;
List<String> seekBarStep = Arrays.asList("All","1","5","10","20");
mDistanceSeekBar.setAdapter(seekBarStep);
```

This will create a black segmented seekbar using default drawables. If you need to add some customization have a look at  **ComboSeekBar.onDraw()**, **CustomDrawable.draw()** and **CustomThumbDrawable.draw()**.

This project is all but finished but still a solid starting point. You probably will have to workout the drawables a bit more

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just "fake it" by making some right adjustment to the images. The only problem would be that it should be length fixed, or at last you should do the text by coding.
Anyway with `android:thumb="@drawable/seek_handler"` you can change the handler style of a seekbar. (See this [Android SeekBar thumb Customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983910/android-seekbar-thumb-customization?rq=1) )

Answer (score 1):

You can check this. This may give you some idea:
[custom seek bar](http://www.tutomobile.fr/realiser-une-progressbar-seekbar-personnalisee-sur-android-tutoriel-android-n%C2%B024/10/02/2011/)

And its source code is here:
[Source code](http://www.mediafire.com/?ndt1drc6ucomwev)

Comment: Always use github or similar sites where we can see your code without having to download your source code.