# how to fix error (android studio)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

i'm beginner. I make metronom, and after i made a layout i have error (link to a screenshot). I can give link in github.

Screenshot android monitor
[image]

code activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.test.metronom.MainActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_manual_mode"
        android:text="@string/manual_mode"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        style="@style/textViewStyle"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/background_footer"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/vibration"
            style="@style/changeMode">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/vibration_image"
                style="@style/imageChangeMode"
                android:src="@drawable/vb"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_vibration"
                style="@style/textChangeMode"
                android:text="@string/tv_vibration" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fi"
            style="@style/changeMode">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fi_image"
                style="@style/imageChangeMode"
                android:src="@drawable/fi"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_fi"
                style="@style/textChangeMode"
                android:text="@string/tv_flash"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sound"
            style="@style/changeMode">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/volume_image"
                style="@style/imageChangeMode"
                android:src="@drawable/sound"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_sound"
                style="@style/textChangeMode"
                android:text="@string/tv_sound"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_set_bpm"
        style="@style/textViewStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="@string/tv_set_bpm"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_bpm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tv_bpm"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textColor="@color/standart"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/minus"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/swipe"
            android:thumb="@drawable/arrows1"
            android:indeterminate="true"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/plus"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tv_indicator"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_indicator"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/indicator"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_start"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background_footer"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/btn_start"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `@drawable/minus` could not be found. Did you properly defined it in your resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it shows that your ImageButton cannot inflate the resource that you have provided

> android:src="@drawable/minus"

check there is **minus.xml** missing in your project

Comment: Thanx, and i have one more qestion: in my seekbar i have android:thumb="@drawable/arrows1", and this thumb in my smartphone be below progress line, but in preview in android studio to be on progress line

Comment: this might be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983910/android-seekbar-thumb-customization